# Treeview.selectednode gives wrong value

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview which have several childs and many of them have ancestors.
I also have a datagridview along side the treeview. Based on treeview selected node, I bind data in Datagridview.

I use `treeView1.SelectedNode` to get the node value 
My problem is that this expression give the previously selected node.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    node = e.node;
}
```

this give me correct node (selected node).
but

`node =  treeview1.selectednode` give the node which I selected earlier.
I want to get the selected node outside the click event (_nodemouseclick).

How can I get It.
I dont want to save node in global variable then use it.

Hope I am clear to explain my question.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Use the AfterSelect event instead.

Comment: No problem to save it in global variable after you get the correct node. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    TreeNode yourGlobalTreeNode;
    void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        yourGlobalTreeNode = e.Node;
        otherFunction();
        anOtherFunction(e.Node);
    }
    void otherFunction()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(yourGlobalTreeNode.Text);
    }
    void anOtherFunction(TreeNode tn)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tn.Text);
    }
```

Other Function means you can use this tree_node anywhere using above two methods.

Comment: Private is not necessary to write, it is the default protection level.

Answer (score 1):

It is because MouseClick event is raised before selectedNode is changed. Try to use SelectedItemChanged event instead

```
    private void TreeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {

    }
```